# Not able to calculate in XSLT after switching the PHP locale

Tags: php, xslt

To get "," instead of "." as a decimal point, I set the locale via setlocale("de_DE");.

When I now transform an XSLT stylesheet that contains a calculation like:

```
<xsl:variable name="a">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$someboolean">
         <xsl:value-of select="0.5"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$a + 2"/>
```

returns NaN.

```
<xsl:value-of select="$a"/>
```

brings me a "0,5", which is good. But the NaN as a result of $a+2 is not what I expected.

Why is $a contverted to text? Am I doing the calculation wrong? Is this behaviour a bug?

---

To make myself clear. Is this the right behaviour of XSLT?

```
<xsl:variable name="a"><xsl:value-of select="0.5"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$a"/> <!-- gives 0,5 --> 
<xsl:value-of select="$a + 2"/> <!-- gives NaN --> 
<xsl:variable name="b" select="0.5"/> 
<xsl:value-of select="$b"/> <!-- gives 0,5 --> 
<xsl:value-of select="$b + 2"/> <!-- gives 2,5 -->
```

---

The complete testing code:

```
<?php
printf("%.1f",0.5);  // gives 0.5
setlocale (LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8', 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'deu_deu', 'deu', 'de', 'ge');
printf("%.1f",0.5);  // gives 0,5

$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->loadXML('<a>a</a>');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->substituteEntities = TRUE;
$xsl->loadXML('
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:variable name="a"><xsl:value-of select="0.5"/></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$a"/>      <!-- gives 0,5 -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$a + 2"/>  <!-- gives NaN -->

            <xsl:variable name="b" select="0.5"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$b"/>      <!-- gives 0,5 -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$b + 2"/>  <!-- gives 2,5 -->
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>');

$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are constructs provided in XSLT to do this:

1. Declare a [**decimal-format**](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_decimal-format.asp) with the "," as the decimal separator.
2. Use the [**format-number**](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/func_formatnumber.asp) function and specify the declared **decimal-format**.

*Note: **decimal-format** has to be declared at the top level of the stylesheet.*

```
<xsl:decimal-format name="european" decimal-separator=',' grouping-separator='.' />
```

When you want your numbers formatted with "," use **format-number** with the **decimal-format**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($a+2, '###.###,00', 'european')"/>
```

Comment: You explain how I transform a number into text. But my problem is the other way round. I have a number (select="0.5"), which is transformed automatically into a string. So that $a becomes "0,5". How do I prevent this?

Comment: Did this problem start after you switched the locale to de_DE?  Do you need that locale, or were you using that to get the "," as the separator in your output?  You could also try explicitly selecting that value as a number, rather than relying on the XSLT engine to "duck type" it:  <xsl:value-of select="number('0.5')"/>

Comment: I switched the locae because of other PHP stuff. That this changes something inside XSLT was not wat I wanted.

Using number() does not help.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing that behavior.  Maybe you could replace the "." with "," and see if it evaluates as a number? translate(0.5, '.',',')

Comment: If I enter "0,5" instead of "0.5" I get an error, since "0,5" is not a number nor a string in XPath. If I enter "'0,5'" I also get an error, since XPath is not able to parse the string.

Comment: Thanks for posting the full example.  I think your problem is that  the value assigned to $a is being evaluated a string instead of a number, since you are calling value-of.

From the spec: "The xsl:value-of element is instantiated to create a text node in the result tree. The required select attribute is an expression; this expression is evaluated and the resulting object is converted to a string as if by a call to the string function. The string specifies the string-value of the created text node" http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#value-of

Answer (score 0):

What you are mixing is output format and numerical value. The xsl expressions are not localized, therefore the decimal comma is not seen as a valid part of the value.

Comment: True, I understand now. But how do I prevent XSLT from transforming my 0.5 to 0,5?